# fscanf crashing my C program, no idea why

Tags: c, scanf

EDIT: Question answered, I had a typo in my first for loop.  Thanks so much everyone for catching that.
I'm working a C project for uni, and I'm having a problem I just cannot figure out.  In one section of the program, I have to read in a few strings of symbols into a 2D character array in a struct (aka a "stamp").  Here is the code in my function:

```
stamp_t * read_stamp_type1(FILE * fptr)
{
    //variable declaration
    int r = 0, c = 0;

    //creating a struct stamp_t and mallocing memory
    stamp_t *newstamp1;
    newstamp1 = malloc(sizeof(stamp_t));

    //reading in values for the rows and columns of the "stamp" to be read in
    fscanf(fptr, "%d %d\n", &r, &c);

    //storing these values
    newstamp1->num_rows = r;
    newstamp1->num_cols = c;

    //creating memory for newstamp1's grid
    newstamp1->grid = malloc(sizeof(char *) * (r));
    for(int i=0; i < c; i++)
        newstamp1->grid[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * (c+1));

    //string to temporarily store input
    char rowvalues[c+1];

    //Note: Everything works up until this point
    //the below lines crash the program every time
    for(int i = 0; i < r; i++)
    {
        fscanf(fptr, "%s", rowvalues);
        for (int j=0; j < c; j++)
            strcpy(newstamp1->grid[i], rowvalues);

    }

    free(rowvalues);

    return(newstamp1);

}
```

For some reason when I try to fscanf the string from the text file, it crashes the program (or at least that's what I think the cause is...).
For reference, here is the struct declaration:

```
// A structure for holding a stamp
typedef struct
{
   // The size of the contents of this stamp.
   int num_rows;
   int num_cols;

   // A 2D array of characters for a stamp.
   char **grid;
} stamp_t;
```

And here is the input to the program:

```
3 4
.#.@ 
#.#. 
.#.@
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated, I can't seem to find any problem with the code. I have tried manually assigning values to each value in the rowvalues array, which works fine (rowvalues[0] = 'c'; works fine).  I need to read in the 3 lines of symbols into newstamp1.grid, which is a 2D array.  I ran a debugger and it said it's try to write to memory that is not allowed ("Access violation writing location").  I emailed my professor but he hasn't be in class for the past week and he isn't responding to email...
Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: This sounds like it might be an unrelated memory error. Have you run your code in valgrind to see if it detects anything fishy?

Comment: If only valgrind were used, and the messages read and understood. None of this is terribly difficult; I reckon a ten year old could accomplish it... You should try some time!

Comment: thanks for your useful input @Seb, with that logic I'll write a letter to my university right now saying we can fire all our professors and just tell students to install valgrind!  Should save them a lot of money--I guess we just weren't aware that everyone is now born with innate programming knowledge, and there is no more need to learn how to do things.  I'd like to know what programs you were writing at the age of 10, and I seriously doubt you learned to code without help from someone.

Comment: Thank you to everyone else who gave useful input, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

For starters there is a typo in this loop

```
newstamp1->grid = malloc(sizeof(char *) * (r));
for(int i=0; i < c; i++)
             ^^^^^^
    newstamp1->grid[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * (c+1));
```

There must be

```
for(int i=0; i < r; i++)
             ^^^^^^
```

This loop

```
    for (int j=0; j < c; j++)
        strcpy(newstamp1->grid[i], rowvalues);
```

does not make sense. It seems you mean just

```
strcpy(newstamp1->grid[i], rowvalues);
```

Or maybe you have to allocate a 3D character array (that is a two dimensional array of strings) if each row in the file contains `c` strings.

And this statement

```
free(rowvalues);
```

is wrong. The variable `rowvalues` has automatic storage duration. So you may not call the function `free` for it.

Comment: Yeah, I like this answer. It's more detailed than mine. :-)

Comment: This worked great....sorry the free statement was leftover from when I was malloc'ing rowvalues, I changed it to a static allocation later on.  Thanks so much, I think the first loop typo was the problem, because it created 3 spaces when I needed 4.  Really appreciate it, it's working well now :)

Answer (score 2):

This part of your code is nonsense:

```
newstamp1->grid = malloc(sizeof(char *) * (r));
for(int i=0; i < c; i++)
    newstamp1->grid[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * (c+1));
```

You allocate `r` items, and then your `for` is repeated as `c`-times. This should be the same, either both `r`, or both `c`. I bet `i < r` is correct condition there.

Also, as Vlad from Moscow pointed out, there is one more bug in the code: The final `free` shouldn't be there at all, because it wasn't `malloc`ated. And the `for-j` line can also be omitted. (But it shouldn't produce any errors, it just unneededly repeats the same code.)

Comment: Whoops, I didn't catch that error.  Thanks!  That helps a lot.

Comment: Could also say that `sizeof(char)` is always 1, and `newstamp1->grid[i] = malloc(c+1);` can suffice. This also brings up that `malloc()` should also be checked all the time.